Why testing a date passes in the localhost but fails in the Azure pipeline?
I have this unit test :
import { describe, expect, it } from "@jest/globals"

import { format2APIDate } from "../helpers"

describe("format2APIDate()", () => {
  it("should return a date with the format: YYYY/MM/DD for date with this format YYYY-MM-DD", () => {
    const date = new Date("2024-02-12")

    const formattedDate = format2APIDate(date)

    expect(formattedDate).toBe("2024/02/12")
  })

  it("should return a date with the format: YYYY/MM/DD when a date has this format", () => {
    const date = new Date("Mon Feb 12 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)")

    const formattedDate = format2APIDate(date)

    expect(formattedDate).toBe("2024/02/12")
  })
})


When I run the tests locally:
npm run test.
They are passed.

However, when I merge the changes, the last test fails:

This is format2APIDate:
export const format2APIDate = (date: Date) => {
  // Format the date as "YYYY/MM/DD"
  const formattedDate = new Date(date)
  return `${formattedDate.getFullYear()}/${String(formattedDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0")}/${String(formattedDate.getDate()).padStart(2, "0")}`
}



What does format2APIDate does? Maybe something is using wrong timezone when calling it? E.g. 2024/02/12 00:00:00 GMT+3 is equal to 2024/02/11 21:00:00 UTC

HI @Justinas, I updated my question. I believe the issue is due the configuration of timezone in the server.

Does this answer your question? JavaScript's getDate returns wrong date

In Azure Pipelines, it uses UTC time (GMT+0) that is 1 hour behind than your time zone. In your test code, the date-time "2024/02/12 00:00:00 GMT+1" will be calculated to be "2024/02/11 23:00:00 GMT+0" (or "2024/02/11 23:00:00 UTC").
You can try to adjust any of the following things in your test code:

Adjust the time zone to be UTC (GMT+0).
Adjust the hour of time to be large than 1. For example, 02:00:00.


Azure Build agents may be placed in different time zones. When you create in GMT+0100, the local time of the cloud build agent may be GMT+0300. Therefore, it will contain another local date for const date = new Date("Mon Feb 12 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)").
